# Python import statement in a loop: does import run every loop iteration?

Tags: python, module, scope, scipy

For a code I am writing, I am running `scipy.curve_fit()` tens of thousands of times.  I noticed in the [relevant `curve_fit()` source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py), specifically on [lines 430](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L430) and 431 in the source (in the `leastsq()` function), there are two `import` statements:

```
from numpy.dual import inv
from numpy.linalg import LinAlgError
```

I call `curve_fit()` inside a loop.  I am wondering if the modules loaded by these `import` statements are kept once an iteration of the loop is completed or if the modules fall out of scope and need to be reloaded in every iteration of the loop.

Note: the `import` statements are only called if the `if full_output:` statement on line 427 of the source code evaluates to true.  `full_output=1` is what is passed to `leastsq()` by `curve_fit()`, so the `import` statements are indeed called.

Additional note: I am **not asking about importing modules multiple times (so much)**, but rather if a module imported in a loop is still accessible by the code after the loop completes (or after each iteration of the loop).

More notes:

```
>>>for x in range(0,1):
...     import os
... 
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/home/lars/env/common/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'>
```

this works, but if I instead define a function:

```
def a(b):
    if a==True:
       import scipy
```

then

```
for i in range(10):
   a(True)
scipy
NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined
```

What is up with that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296036/does-python-optimize-modules-when-they-are-imported-multiple-times, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487549/how-safe-is-it-to-import-a-module-multiple-times

Comment: @ev-br, those questions are not quite what I am asking.  I am essentially asking if modules imported in a loop fall out of scope when the loop iteration ends, or if the code holds on to them.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has nothing to do with a loop, it's all about this funciton.
As doc sais,

> The basic import statement (no from clause) is executed in two steps:
>      find a module, loading and initializing it if necessary
>       define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where the import statement occurs.

And funcitons do have their own scope, that's why you can't see imported module outside of it.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement