# PYTHON Need help simplifying - generating random items from a pre-set list

Tags: python, python-2.x

I know there's an easier way to do this. It is supposed to be a "Simon" like game where you generate 5 random colors from the list and the user enters the colors. Each turn it should keep the 1st color the same and add a new random color, which is where my trouble is coming in. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import random
# Create a list of colors.
colors = ['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue']

# Generate random colors from the list. 
color1 = random.choice(colors)
color2 = random.choice(colors)
color3 = random.choice(colors)
color4 = random.choice(colors)
color5 = random.choice(colors)


# Simon displays the 5 color choices, adding 1 each turn. 

print "Simon says: ", color1
raw_input ("What did Simon say? ")

print "Simon says: ", color1, color2
raw_input ("What did Simon say? ")

print "Simon says: ", color1, color2, color3
raw_input ("What did Simon say? ")

print "Simon says: ", color1, color2, color3, color4
raw_input ("What did Simon say? ")

print "Simon says: ", color1, color2, color3, color4, color5
raw_input ("What did Simon say? ")
```

My first try looked like this but was not working either:

```
# Create a list of colors.
colors = ['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue']


# Display the color list, adding one random color each turn. Prompt the
# user to enter the colors after each is added.
for i in range (5):
    import random
    color = random.choice(colors)

    print "Simon says: " ,color

    raw_input ("What did Simon say? ")
    colors.append(colors)
    print "Simon says: " , (color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Your issue is to try and modify your original 4-color list. Just initialize a new, empty list for the gameplay:

```
# Create a list of colors.
colors = ['Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', 'Blue']

# Display the color list, adding one random color each turn. Prompt the
# user to enter the colors after each is added.
chosen_colors = []
for i in range (5):
    import random
    color = random.choice(colors)
    chosen_colors.append(color)
    print "Simon says: " ,chosen_colors
    raw_input ("What did Simon say? ")
```

Now you should find a way to check if the answer is correct or not.

Comment: Thank you! I took a programming course a few years back and am now taking a separate one, where I can only use what we've learned up until this point. So for this program I can't add checking the answer, but if I could I think I would use if/else statements.

Comment: It is a bit silly placing the import statement inside the loop. You're essentially calling the import 5 times! All imports should be at the top.

Comment: @SurajKothari I tried to make minimal modifications to the OP's code. Thank you for pointing out that. That being said, there is no performance penalty doing this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487549/how-safe-is-it-to-import-a-module-multiple-times) for details.